# Trigger azure Webjob from powershell / azure devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-webjobs

Is there any idea that shows how to trigger (or start) a azure web app webjob from azure devops task ( or via azure powershell) ?

Thank you,

Edit : i use the azure cli task in azure devops
it's look no working

EDIT 2 : i'am wrong in name of slot
the solution of @levi-lu-msft Works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the extension task [Azure App Services (With WebJob) - Start and Stop](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=amel.appservices-start-stop&targetId=47097972-e633-4284-ad72-fe49f3c8dd5f) to start a azure web app webjob.

You can also run below [ac cli command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/webjob/triggered?view=azure-cli-latest#az_webapp_webjob_triggered_run) in the [azure cli task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-cli?view=azure-devops) to start a webjob.

`az webapp webjob triggered run --name MyWebApp --resource-group MyResourceGroup --webjob-name MyWebjob`

You will need to connect your azure devops to Azure subscription by creating an [Azure Resource Manager service connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/connect-to-azure?view=azure-devops)

Comment: Thanks for your reply , this command can't run with manually webjob ?

Comment: @QuentinMerlin To run a specific triggered webjob you can try using `az webapp webjob triggered run --name MyWebApp --resource-group MyResourceGroup --webjob-name MyWebjob`.

Comment: Thanks ! Work like a charm

Answer (score 2):

You can use Powershell to trigger Manual Azure Webapp Webjob.

The user name and password comes from their Publishing profile. (In the Azure Portal ->  browse to Your App Service > Click on "Get Publish Profile")

The $username in the script should look like `SomeUserName`, and **not** `SomeSite\SomeUserName`

```
$username = "`$username"

$password = "password"

$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $username, $password)))

$userAgent = "powershell/1.0"

$apiUrl = "https://<sitename>.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/triggeredwebjobs/<YourWebjobName>/run"

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $apiUrl -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -UserAgent $userAgent -Method POST -Debug
```

Comment: not working for me : Invoke-WebRequest : Windows PowerShell is in NonInteractive mode. Read and Prompt functionality is not available. i use azuredevops to run this command via Powershell task